# What is the anti-derivative of a sectionally defined function`?

Tags: calculus, integration

so suppose $f(x)=\begin{cases}1 \text{ if } x>-1 \\ -2 \text{ if } x\leq -1\end{cases}$. Could you say that $F(x)=\begin{cases}x+C \text{ if } x>-1 \\ -2x+C \text{ if } x\leq -1\end{cases}$.

Is that possible?

Comment: Those functions are antiderivatives in that at each point where they are differentiable (i.e. all points except -1) their derivative is $f$. Typically we prefer an antiderivative to be continuous even if it cannot be differentiable, so you would want to require $-1+C_1=2+C_2$.

Answer (score 2):

If as antiderivative you mean a function F(x) such that for **every**  real x it is
$$
F'(x) = f(x)
$$
your function does not have any primitive due to the [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)).

Shortly: if a function admits a derivative for each real x then either such derivative is continuous or it has Essential discontinuities.